# Run Python Interpreter in Rosetta mode in VSCode for macOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python, rosetta-2

I am trying to get used to the Debugger from VSCode for macOS. However, I am developing an app in `arm64` and `x86_64` (Rosetta2, Intel, or however you wanna call it). For this I have two different Python `venv`s. Normally I just debug it by executing it in the terminal. For the `arm64` mode I just run `python script.py` and for the `x86_64` app I first start an Rosetta2 `zsh` with `arch -x86_64 zsh` and then run the `python script.py` (of course from a different `venv` that has also been created using the Rosetta2 `zsh`. Is there a way to tell VSCode to execute the Python intepreter (from the `venv`) in Rosetta2 mode?

Thanks